# get one result at a time from database (when more than one result exists)

Tags: java, sql, database, psql

I have a database in which more than one row has the same value.
Eg,

> Column1 Column2
>
> ```
> A       X
> A       Y
> A       Z
> ```

A resultset gets all the values of column 2  as a single string.
How to get each unique value from database (or from result set)?

(I use java)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a unique id for each row...

Comment: No, a `ResultSet` gives you row-at-a-time access to the query results.  Please clarify why you think you will get all the column 2 values as a single string.

Comment: No, what I meant was for a query 'SELECT COLUMN2' FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE 'A';' and Java code like                              String out = rs.getString(1); System.out.println(out); gives                                                                     X                                                                          Y                                                                         Z as a single string. So, I wanted to know whether I can get them seperately to be stored in an array.

Comment: That code will not do that.  Please update your post and copy/paste the actual code fragment from your IDE that you believe is doing this, including the query being executed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What is the query/code you are using to get all of column two as a string? It is always a good idea to test your query in the database system itself or you could use [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) to ensure you are getting the results you are expecting from your query

From the Doc:

> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

Read the rest of [Java Doc for ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

A typical approach to getting values from the data base is to

```
//Construct a statement
String yourStatement = "Select COLUMN_B from aTable WHERE COLUMN_A LIKE 'A'" // EDITED
PreparedStatement aPrepStatement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(); // ADDED
try
{
   aPrepStatement = yourConnection.prepareStatement(yourStatement)
   rs = aPrepStatement.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next())
   {
       // You are now in the first row of data depending on your query
       // String column1 = rs.getString(1);   // 'A' In the table you descrbed above (for first iteration
       String column2 = rs.getString(1);   // 'X' In the table you descrbed above
       // Now do what you need to with the data
       aList.add(column2)  // EDITED

   }
 }
 catch (Exception ex) {
      // deal with any exceptions that arise
      ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally
{
    //Close your Resultset and prepared statement (this will possibly need a try catch block also
    if(rs != null)
        rs.close();
    if(aPrepStatement != null)
        aPrepStatement.close();
}
// ADDED BELOW
for(String s: aList)
    System.out.println(s) // should give output
                          // X
                          // Y
                          // Z
```

Doc for [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation. I had already done what you have specified.                                                       I give query as 'SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE 'A';'   Then,                                                           String output=rs.getString(1); System.out.println(output);        This code gives me output as                                        X                                                                   Y                                                                   Z altogether. So, what am I missing?

Comment: @user2472134 Thats good! I've edited above to your example, try adding each string to a list then you can do what you want with the list. You should update the question with the code you have already so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
SELECT columna ,
(SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT columnb SEPARATOR ' ') FROM test 
WHERE columna=t.`columna` ) as columnb_string    
FROM `test` t GROUP BY columna
```

Here is **[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61e7f/4)**